# NuxtJS automatically adds script at the end of the body

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm a newbie NuxtJS programmer. I just searched all over the internet but couldn't find the answer.

I'm just wondering that is it natural that NuxtJS automatically adds the script at the end of the body described as below.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.oncontextmenu = null;
        document.onselectstart = null;
        document.ondragstart = null;
        document.onmousedown = null;
        document.body.oncontextmenu = null;
        document.body.onselectstart = null;
        document.body.ondragstart = null;
        document.body.onmousedown = null;
        document.body.oncut = null;
        document.body.oncopy = null;
        document.body.onpaste = null;
</script>
```

Everytime I change my page, it keeps adding this script, so it stacks the same script over and over.

Do you guys have any ideas why this is happening?

I also searched entire code where it does add this script but couldn't find it.

I can give any informations you need, so please help me with this problem.

Many thanks!!!

Comment: It does that in dev mode right (when you're working on your code) or in production (where your app is published)? If it's the case, it's probably coming from HMR (hot module reload) and should not be an issue per-se. You will not find anything regarding that issue on the Internet and to find that, you gonna need to dive into Nuxt's internals, but there is no real need for such. You can mainly move along.

Comment: I just tested in production mode, but does the same thing.

Comment: How are you changing your page? Do you have a [repro]?

Comment: I'm changing my page with <NuxtLink> tag, like <NuxtLink to="/">home</NuxtLink> or use this.$router.push('/') in methods.

Comment: Maybe should I show you my nuxt.config.js? Maybe plugins or middlewares can be the problem. But I didn't add any middleware or plugins that add those codes as far as I know.

Comment: I think that behaviour is only done in firefox browser. I checked in the chrome it didn't happened. Still don't know why.. But I think the problem is solved. Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe a blocker of some sort done by Firefox yeah. Maybe try into a private window, could also be a browser extension.

Comment: It can also be some prefetch thing? Not sure exactly.

Comment: I tried in a private window, but still the same.. But didn't think adblocker can be the cause... I enabled adblocker even in the private window. I just came back home so not sure but maybe I should check it back later. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this one is added only on Chrome and not Firefox, and looking at the code added, I guess that you can simply ignore that one and move along (something on your side and not directly related to Nuxt).